# How do I add a column that counts unique instances of another columns data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am an end user that does not work with SQL everyday.
However I am sometimes asked to add modify existing queries to provide new data.

Currently I have a query that calculates (counts) the occurrences of a column labeled
(Qid) and displays the top 5 based on count.
It was necessary to use a select statement within a select statement to do this
(I had to get some help)

I am being asked if it is possible to add a column that counts the unique instances of column entries "Scan_Run_Date_Week"
for each of those associated top 5 QID. The new column is designed to display how many unique weeks the correlating QID has been present. (I Refer to it as "Time on Track")

Attached below is a sample set of the data being worked with.
How would I modify my existing query to include this newly desired column (Time_On_Track)

Kindest regards,

Runatyr

```
Select 
       QID_Count,
       QID,
       Scan_Run_Date_Week,
       Title,
       Severity
From
        (
        SELECT count(QID) as QID_Count, 
               QID,
               Scan_Run_Date_Week, 
               Title,
               row_number() over(partition by Scan_Run_Date_Week order by count(QID) desc) as Ranking,
               Severity

        FROM dbo.RMO_Qualys_PROD 

        Where Severity = '5' and Scan_Run_Date_Week = '2021-06-06 00:00:00.000'


        Group By Scan_Run_Date_Week, Title, QID, Severity
        ) as Ranking
Where Ranking <=5
```

[image: Raw Data]

[image: Existing Query Results]

Comment: You have a filter on `Scan_Run_Date_Week` so they are all going to be the same. And `COUNT(QID)` just counts non-null rows in the group, it doesn't do a distinct count unless you specify `COUNT (DISTINCT`

Comment: I was just about to say that....

Comment: So this table can have multiple QID because you are storing a date against them? im finding it very hard to understand what you want, are you able to show use what you expect to get, as I am confused by " unique instances of column entries "Scan_Run_Date_Week" for each of those associated top 5 QID"

Comment: @Andrew The Raw Data image shows that the QID is not unique. We are first trying to find the QID's that occur the most (Top 5) that also match parameters when ran (the week specified, the severity.  Then from those top 5 results returned ... we want to take the QID displayed and count how many weeks that QID has been present.

Comment: Would this be consecutive weeks? so if there was a break of a week say after 3 weeks in the past then you would only show that it has be present for 3 weeks? Gordon has done his magic of providing an answer, but I will have to go and experiment as I don't really understand dense rank

Comment: You query filters by a specific date, so are you saying there can be many of the same QID for the same date? it maybe ties in with the first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support `count(distinct)` as a window function, but there is a workaround using the sum of two `dense_rank()`s.  So I think you want:

```
Select QID_Count, QID, Scan_Run_Date_Week, Title, Severity,
       num_scan_run_date_week
From (SELECT count(QID) as QID_Count, QID, Scan_Run_Date_Week,  Title,
             row_number() over(partition by Scan_Run_Date_Week order by count(QID) desc) as Ranking,
             Severity,
             (-1 + dense_rank() over (partition by qid order by scan_run_date_week asc) +
              dense_rank() over (partition by qid order by scan_run_date_week desc)
             ) as num_scan_run_date_week
      FROM dbo.RMO_Qualys_PROD 
      Where Severity = '5' and
            Scan_Run_Date_Week = '2021-06-06 00:00:00.000'
      Group By Scan_Run_Date_Week, Title, QID, Severity
     ) as Ranking
Where Ranking <= 5;
```